# How do I configure the rewrite and map prefixed dynamic route path in firebase hosting and functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have firebase page and functions enabled. I want to have a api routes like the following:

1. ***https://mmydomain.com/api/generatorPerson***
2. ***https://mmydomain.com/api/generateLead***
3. ***https://mmydomain.com/api/and_so_on***

I did follow this guide from Firebase team https://youtu.be/LOeioOKUKI8 (Dynamic Node apps) in which he mapped or hooked the path **https://mmydomain.com/timestamp** to the firebase function 'exports.app' where he has */timestamp* express route path. His code is something like the one below:

*functions/index.json*

```
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = express();

app.get('/timestamp', (request, response) =>{
    response.send('${Date.now()}');
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

*public/firebase.json*

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/timestamp",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now my goal is kinda the same but I want to prefix the path with 'api' so that I can have api paths that I listed above. I tried working first the ***https://mmydomain.com/api/generatorPerson*** using the functions setup/config and firebase config below. It deploys with no error but I get 404 error.

*functions/index.json*

```
const faker = require('faker');
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const app = express();

app.get('/api/generatePerson', (request, response) =>{
    let randomName = faker.name.findName();
    let randomEmail = faker.internet.email();
    let randomPhoneNumber = faker.phone.phoneNumber();
    let randomBirthDay = faker.date.past();
    let randomAddress = faker.address.streetAddress();
    let randomJobTitle = faker.name.jobTitle();
    let randomJobDescription = faker.name.jobDescriptor();
    let randomCompany = faker.company.companyName();

    let person = {
        name: randomName,
        email: randomEmail,
        phoneNumber: randomPhoneNumber,
        birthday: randomBirthDay,
        address: randomAddress,
        work: {
            jobTitle: randomJobTitle,
            jobDescription: randomJobDescription,
            company: randomCompany
        }
    };

    response.send(person);
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

*public/firebase.json*

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

I used pattern `/api/**`since I want all the sub routes be prefixed with api and mapped them to the `exports.app`. What's the problem of my code? Or am I doing the prefixing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to demonstrate exactly what request URL should map to what function.  As your question stands now, it's hard to tell exactly what it is that's not working the way you expect.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Hi thanks for responding. I'm sorry I haven't articulated my question clearly. I edited the question and the content I hope it does clear things up.

Comment: Please be more specific.  You're giving url paths right now rather than what the full URL looks like.  You don't have to give up the name of your project or anything, but it would help us to know more exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Or, to put things another way, if I wanted to reproduce your situation, what are the exact steps I could take to see what you're seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolved the problem by:

1. Cleaned the firebase.json with any comment artifacts.
2. Deploy both hosting and functions.
3. If the problem still there wait a couple of minutes or refresh the http call of your API. After that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
app.get('/generatePerson', (request, response) =>{
```

/api is already mapped to the express app

Comment: Hi thanks for responding I do get an error: Cannot GET /api/generatePerson